# Docker file paths format - How to access files from their paths in docker?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Code runs perfectly on my machine with flask data input. I built a docker container with all the requirements and versions installed and code is running. However the file path format seems to be off. If I have a weight file in the main directory for example, I am currently accessing it this way:

```
original_directory = os.path.abspath("../../") # file I am running is 2 levels down from docker files
path_needed = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "file.h5") # file is at the same level as docker files
```

The above code is not finding the file in docker. I get the following error:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '/file.h5', errno = 2,
        error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0) // Werkzeug Debugger
```

It also can't access it if I give it its name by itself such as

```
path_needed='file.h5' # also not working inside docker
```

How do the paths work in docker? Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is probably using docker exec to enter your container and peek around at the file structure

Comment: If I run it and list its files the files show inside at the right paths... it is a question of path format I guess.. not sure how docker handles paths.

Comment: Paths work in a docker container the same way they do on the host you're running it. It is likely that the directory tree is not what you think. Show us your Dockerfile.

Comment: You should do a print of  the contents of your `ROOT_DIR` from within  your python file to help debugging

Comment: everything is there as it should. It just doesn't read/find the file inside the container.